# Web audio stream

Tags: flash, audio, stream, ffmpeg

What's a good solution for web audio streaming?

I've read about Flash Media Server, but that's a little too expensive right now, it seems easier than other solutions but can't afford it.

There is FFmpeg, FFserver, Icecast and SSH among the popular.

What I want is an easy solution for the user, which I was thinking something with flash. Load up FFmpeg/FFserver or Icecast as server stream and read that stream with a flash player inside the webpage. (I don't want to force users to download VLC or winamp)

I'm not sure if I'm going the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Red5 is probably what you want: http://www.red5.org/

Comment: +1 Red 5 is indeed a very nice alternative to the all too expensive FMS

Comment: I forgot to add "live" word. But I can see Red5 supports that as well. So basically, I install Red5 server, start it up. Then with Flash Media Live Encoder transmit data to Red5 server and with flowplayer, users can listen what I'm transmitting?

Comment: Sounds about right: I've honestly never used Flash Media Live Encoder with Red5 though (all I've done is live audio chat).

Comment: Which program are you using instead of FMLE?

Comment: Whipped together a chintzy little microphone streaming client in OpenLaszlo (see http://www.openlaszlo.org/) and then wrote a tiny amount of Java code to let me tie any 2 client streams together through my Red5 server. Worked well enough, if not the prettiest thing on the planet.

Answer (score 1):

Wowza is an alternative option: http://www.wowza.com/